# JAVA BOX SDK from Eclipse to Grails using GGTS

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, box, ggts

I am using BOX JAVA SDK and ran those functionalities in Eclipse, which worked fine.

I added all the jar files I used in eclipse to GGTS. But when I add the packages to Grails (java->src->package_name), it throws an exception all the time.

What else could be preventing me from moving to Grails?

The exception I am getting via Grails is from the second line of:

```
    PEMParser keyReader = new PEMParser(new StringReader(this.privateKey));
    Object keyPair = keyReader.readObject();
```

The message is:

```
com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey

    Error |
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: problem creating RSA private key: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: [B
Error |
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser$KeyPairParser.parseObject(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.readObject(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at com.box.sdk.BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.decryptPrivateKey(BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.java:378)
Error |
```

Answer (score 0):

is grails using the same jdk?  I had to put the 2 security files in jre/lib/security for this to work.

Comment: Eclipse java 1.8 and Grails Java 1.8_121 ... seems same ... security files in the sense jce_policy 8 right ? and since I already executed the same program in eclipse I added the security files already in the folders. but not working in grails....  @kendomen

Comment: Yes.  You're right.  It must be something else.  Sorry!

Comment: any other solutions? Do I need to add to the build path in grails or anything else ? I am stuck in this...